# simulate key typing and reduce 2 of value

Tags: javascript, reduce, simulate

I have some javascript code for typing in input element. it puts 3 in input . here is my code :

```
    var txt = "3";
var timeOut;
var txtLen = txt.length;
var char = 0;
var tb = $("#act_bub input").attr("value", "|");
(function typeIt() {
    var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        char++;
        var type = txt.substring(0, char);
        tb.attr("value", type + '|');
        typeIt();

        if (char == txtLen) {
            tb.attr("value", tb.attr("value").slice(0, -1))
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

    }, humanize);
}());
```

and here is my html code :

```
<div id="test">
<input type="text" value="6">
</div>
```

so how can i make this code to c*heck the value of input element and reduce 2 of it* and put in input ? for example in my input value is 6 , code checks the value then put 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
Here is my html code :
<div id="test">
<input type="number" id="num" value="6">
</div>
Your number is:
<div id='b'></div>

<script>
  var txt = document.getElementById('num').value-2;
  document.getElementById('b').innerHTML=txt;
  var timeOut;
  var txtLen = txt.length;
  var char = 0;
  var tb = $("#act_bub input").attr("value", "|");
  function typeIt() {
    var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (170)) + 30;
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        char++;
        var type = txt.substring(0, char);
        tb.attr("value", type + '|');
        typeIt();

        if (char == txtLen) {
            tb.attr("value", tb.attr("value").slice(0, -1))
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

    }, humanize);
  }
  </script>
```

Use `document.getElementById('id').value` find the value of an input.

Comment: i need somthing that you put in console and it reduce the input value . can you help me ? tnx

Comment: What do you mean, 'console'? Do you want a prompt window?

Comment: javascriptconsole. i use this code for decrement the value :document.getElementById('test').value--; but i want to decrement 2 by 2 for example change 6 to 4 can you help me

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Change `--` to `-2` to decrement a single variable by 2. What else do you need?